# Set OS X application preference to stop prompting for admin password

Tags: macos, passwords, administrator, applescript

I am trying to write an applescript that sends some actions to an application (specifically waterroof).  The problem is, the application periodically asks me for the admin password when I open the settings panel I am interested in.  It works on a time-delay, so if I already entered the password in the previous x minutes, it does not prompt.  Because I can't rely on being asked, I can't consider pausing and entering the password as part of the script.

Is there a way to tell the app/OS that I want to stay logged in to the app with admin privileges, and that it shouldn't ask me?  I want to exhaust this possibility before I attempt to check for its existence etc in code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the timeout for authorization in OS X (if done properly) is set in the [Policy Database](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/02authconcepts/authconcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH205-TPXREF19) located at `etc/authorization`, usually programmatically. It looks like a plist file, and if an item has no 'timeout' key, then it has no timeout.

I do know that the preference is usually set in code using Apple's APIs (as shown in Apple's [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1) and the [function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationRightSet) reference).

This is a protected file. Use something like `sudo pico /private/etc/authorization` to edit it.

The entry in this file will have a title using a kind of descriptor 'com.company.application.right' or something like that (e.g. com.apple.itunes.copy, com.stackexchange.superuser.deleteuser) - which is specific to each application, so look for that. (It's in alphabetical order to make things easier, I believe).

[image]

If there is no such entry, then the app probably grabs authorization in another way which I don't know about. I just tried adding a timeout to an app I wrote - it worked. I then deleted it again - and the timeout disappeared. It should work in your case, I'm guessing.

You do mention a settings panel - if that involves System Preferences then I don't know how it works either. There's no way to do it through applescript.

**Edit: If there is no such entry**

ANOTHER way an application may authorize is using the now deprecated and insecure method `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`. I'm guessing that if an application doesn't have its own entry in the Policy Database, it uses `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`. It may be that the application  you're trying to work with uses this.

There is an entry in the Policy Database for this particular method called `system.privilege.admin`, but note that modifying this and deleting the timeout will probably change the timeout for all applications using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`, not just the one you're trying to change. It may be worth a try.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response and diagramming skills.  Unfortunately there's no entry in there for the application.

Comment: What application might it be?

Comment: I also added some information, see if it helps!